# Representing multiple many-to-one relationships in REST

Tags: rest, uri, many-to-one

I am creating a RESTful API that contains the following resources shown in the following UML-ish diagram. As shown by the multiplicities (between parentheses), there are four one-to-many relationships.

[image: Relationship diagram]

I currently have the following `GET` methods defined:

```
GET /farmers
GET /farmers/[farmer_id]
GET /farms
GET /farms/[farm_id]
GET /llamas
GET /llamas/[llama_id]
GET /events
```

I am trying to decide what is the best and most RESTful way to access these relations, as well as accessing events related to Farms and Farmers (via Llamas). All of these relations will be made available using hypermedia links. The two options I have come up with so far are:

#### Multiple URIs

```
GET /farmers/[farmer_id]/farms
GET /farmers/[farmer_id]/llamas
GET /farmers/[farmer_id]/events
GET /farms/[farm_id]/farmer
GET /farms/[farm_id]/llamas
GET /farms/[farm_id]/events
GET /llamas/[llama_id]/farm
GET /llamas/[llama_id]/farmer
GET /llamas/[llama_id]/events
```

#### Single URIs and Filtering

```
GET /farms?farmer=[farmer_id]
GET /llamas?farmer=[farmer_id]
GET /events?farmer=[farmer_id]
GET /farmers/[farm_farmer_id]
GET /llamas?farm=[farm_id]
GET /events?farm=[farm_id]
GET /farms/[llama_farm_id]
GET /farmers/[llama_farmer_id]
GET /events?llama=[llama_id]
```

Are either of these methods preferred for REST, or can I just pick the one I like the most?

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter from a REST perspective, as long as you provide the links to the client.

From an implementation perspective, you may want to favor one of those options over the others if you're using a framework that uses a specific convention for automatic link relation publishing. For instance, Spring Data REST gives you the multiple URI scheme you defined above out of the box. Therefore, it would be a lot less work for you to simply go with that convention.

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathon W says, it doesn't matter from a REST perspective. However, it does matter from a HTTP perspective.

From HTTP perspective, the multiple URI represents a unique, potentially-cachable resource. Cache control headers will obviously control any caching. However, Most proxies will not cache URIs with a query string, so the single URI with filtering option will generally not be cachable.

You also need to consider what are the consequences of not including the query string parameters. Ie. What would /events output? If the llama_id parameter is required, this is not evident.

Personally, I would go for the multiple URI option

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify: `/events`, `/farmers`, `/farms`, and `/llamas` all have defined outputs even with no query parameters. Good point about the caching though.